# Devise Validation Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm trying to create a Devise user manually. The hitch is that validations only seem to pass when I call `User.create`.

When I call `User.new`, the resulting user instance is invalid. Unfortunately, I can't determine why.

The resulting error message is simply "Validation failed: ".

Any idea what's going on?

I would prefer not to use `User.create` because I want to call `#skip_confirmation!` prior to save, so that there's no email that goes out.

Any ideas how to debug this? I've tried walking through the stack trace, but no luck.

```
if user = User.create(params[:user])
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!
  flash[:success] = "New user #{user.email} created."
  redirect_to user_root_path
else
  flash[:alert] = user.errors
  redirect_to user_root_path
end
```

Comment: have you check the errors object?

Comment: `user = User.create(params[:user])` will always be truthy unless an exception is raised. When you use `User.new(params[:user])`, what are the specific errors? Posting the params hash would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why this works, but it appears that calling `user.confirm!` prior to calling `user.skip_confirmation!` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a password to parameters array.

`params[:user][:password] = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]`

Answer (score 0):

Change the conditional because that value will always answer true. As dwhalen said.